# How to handle relative protocol URL in Chrome Extension 3rd party library

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, relative-url

I'm developing a Chrome extension that relies on a 3rd party javascript library. In the library's code, all of the URLs to their resources and API endpoints use relative protocol, like:

`//blah.com/api/get-the-stuff/`

The issue is that when calls are made from within the extension, I think the the URL becomes something like:

`chrome-extension://blah.com/api/get-the-stuff/`

Obviously this doesn't work. One solution is to alter the 3rd party library to full URLs, like:

`https://blah.com/api/get-the-stuff/`

This works, but really it isn't sustainable to maintain a modified version of this lib.
Is there a way to handle this?

I think the [chrome.webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) looks promising for rewriting the URLs before the request sends, but these relative protocol URLs seem to be failing before they trigger a listener on this API.  The requests show up in the network tab of the developer console as:

`chrome-extension://invalid/`

Is this a rewrite that Chrome is doing to my 
`chrome-extension://blah.com/api/get-the-stuff/` URLs before the request is created?  Do I need to alter my manifest in some way to allow these "bad" URL requests to fire so I can rewrite them?

Or maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely?